# connecting to a local network device using java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols

I am trying to write a java program to communicate/control a network device connected in my LAN. The network device has a web-GUI and uses TCP, I tried to establish a connection with the device using java socket, but the device keep reseting the connection after its established.

I am trying to use wireshark/netcat/tcpflow to sniff the data between the web-GUI and the device, but wireshark is overwhelmed with data, i am still reading on netcat/tcpflow, couldnt find an easy tutorial.

Im just wondering if anyone can shine me some lights on this to get me rolling.

thanks in advance

heres the code i tried

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class draft{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{
        String data;
        String host = new String ("192.168.100.223");
        int port = 80;
        Socket ndsocket = new Socket(host, port);   

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(ndsocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(ndsocket.getInputStream()));
```

from wireshark, it uses HTTP 1.1, should i use something like these to force a http 1.1 connection?

```
    con_out = connection.getOutputStream();
    con_in  = connection.getInputStream();
    PrintWriter out_writer = new PrintWriter(con_out, false);
    out_writer.print("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    out_writer.print("Host: thehost\r\n");
    out_writer.print("\r\n");
    out_writer.flush();
```

from tcpflow, i can see it sends back a http page update, so I will have to somehow parse the code i need, but first need to get connection working.

and I dont have access to the device all the time (its in my brother's house), so I may not be able to test out suggestions as often as i like.

and sorry if i being a noob as im inexperienced on writing my own program, thanks for helping again.

Comment: please show some code of how do you connect to the server

Comment: @jdevelop I don't mind code but that is really a pretty pointless question. It must be some variation on `new Socket(host, port)` or `SocketChannel.open(host, port).` How you connect has little to do with connection resets.

Comment: @EJP he may use some HttpConnector which uses HTTP 1.0 by default or something like that. And connection reset might occur because server closes socket after this header.

Comment: @jdevelop Well he may, but he doesn't mention J2ME anywhere. It's conceivable that he's using a URL/HttpURLConnection as well, but in that case I would expect it to work, provided there is HTTP on the other end of course ;-)

Comment: Actually I didn't mind J2ME at all, I was thinking about Apache Commons. anyway looks like the question is incomplete and not specific, and thus is subject for closing.

Comment: @jdevelop i used `Socket ndsocket = new Socket(host, port)` with the device local network address and port 80, `new DataOutputstream(ndsocket.getOutputStream())` and `new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(ndsocket.getInputStream)` for sending and receiving data

Comment: why not to use URLConnection class ? It's easier and less error-prone.

Comment: @jdevelop There is zero evidence here that he is using a protocol supported by URLConnection. What the protocol is is in fact the missing part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The device keep reseting the connection after its established

That probably means you aren't sending it the correct protocol. You're going to have to find out what that is, and only you can do that, as only you know what the device is.